# Android runtime permission not working

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions

I have called permission function from the onCreate method of the activity which should set the boolean value to true and false accordingly. But the boolean variable is not returning true after the permission is granted. Is something wrong with calling verifyStoragePermissions from oncreate method? Please suggest the appropriate way. Thanks.

Note: I have already added the permission on the manifests file.

```
Boolean PermissionGranted = false;
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
public  void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }else{
        PermissionGranted = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
        int requestCode,
        String permissions[],
        int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        PermissionGranted = true;
        System.out.println("P granted");
    } else {
        PermissionGranted = false;
        System.out.println("P not granted");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    verifyStoragePermissions(this);
    if(!PermissionGranted) {
    ...
    }else{
    ...
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: does your log print as it sould be?

Comment: Permission requests are asynchronous. You can't assume that the request is complete directly after calling `verifyStoragePermissions`.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the comment. so what might be the possible way to get it working?

Comment: @maheryhaja: Log shows "P granted", however in onCreate PermissionGranted variable is still set as false.

Comment: By restructuring your code so that anything that requires the permission you're asking for happens when you've received the `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback.

Comment: @Michael Can you please describe with examples. Its hard to grab being a beginner. Thanks.

Comment: Google already have examples in the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting  and  https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions

Answer (score 1):

Your problem according to the code you put here, should be the missing permission in AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

When we deal with permissions, don´t forget to put them in AndroidManifest.

For more information about the permission, please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml file.